# Select only Employees with the job title waiter

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server 2012 and visual studio 2010 and what I have so far is a single table int the database and a small c# application that loads the employees into a `datagridview`

however what I want to do is select only employees with the job title 'Waiter'

So far i have written queries on adding records editing deleting and displaying the whole data.

So far I have managed to display the names only by reading a specified column:

```
      private void LoadEmpName()
      {
            sc.Close();
            try
            {
                sc.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from myEmployees";
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {

                        lstNames.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
                sc.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to change my existing code so that only employees that are listed as 'Waiter' are displayed (first name only) or will i have to write a totally different query?

Comment: Just a note: you don't need `if (dr.HasRows)` - if there are no rows, `dr.Read()` will return false, and the while loop won't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from myEmployees where jobtitle='Waiter'
```

Comment: You may want to add more description in your answer .Like please change your query etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a column called "JobTitle" then your query would become:

```
"select * from myEmployees where JobTitle like '%waiter%'";
```

The "like" is the comparison operator and the "%" is a wildcard of any number of characters.

There are several ways you could go if you want queries for different things. The simplest is to simply create a new method that has the part time test in the query string:

```
"select * from myEmployees where PartTime = 1";
```

However, you will need a new query for each possible search the user could do and this would become inefficient to maintain.

As you are populating a data grid you should look at doing the filtering in the client. You bring all the data (using paging if you have a large amount) and then let the user decide what information they are interested in seeing by specifying their own filters.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `where` clause to your SQL query. I don't know your database structure, but something like;

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from myEmployees where title='waiter'";
```

It is much more efficient to do your filtering in SQL rather than in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Discalimer: The OP asked "Is it possible to change my existing code so that only employees that are listed as 'Waiter' are displayed (first name only) or will i have to write a totally different query?"

So purely to answer that you don't 'have' to use a new query. You could place an if before you add like this(assuming your second column is 'job title'):

```
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if(dr[2].ToString().EqualsIgnoreCase("Waiter")){
                        lstNames.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Although I would not recommend it.

Comment: Could you expand on why you wouldn't recommend it? :)

Comment: Simply because it is not the right way to do it. The right way would be modify the query to only select the rows you need as other posters have mentioned. Its more efficient and cleaner that way.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to change the query . It is better approach.
**I liked @CrisF solution. just addition to it.**

```
    private void LoadEmpName()
    {

        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            //it will return all employees containing word waiter in Column JobTitle.
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from myEmployees where JobTitle like '%waiter%' ";

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
               lstNames.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
           sc.Close();
        }
    }
```